# Using href config in Button xtype changing css of button..How should I fix it?

Tags: css, extjs4

I'm using Button X type in which I have href config to open another link . But using href changing my button style..As I though due to using href config  style has changing..This is my X type..ExtJS4...

```
                      {
                            xtype:'button',
                            text:'Start',
                            style:'margin-left:150px;',
                            cls:'userAccountButtonCls',                             
                            href:'http://localhost/zipyap/',                                                             
                       }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
Handler:function(){
window.location.assign("http://localhost/zipyap/");
}
instead of href
```

Hope it may help